# can't run google map api v2 in eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I follow https://developers.google.com but I can't run google map api v2. 
my source code :
Main activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="permission_name" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyChf959EfDa4Fa408X7MoYErtYsntqt2pU" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It not running. I don't understand. I was install Google Apis. Google Play Services.

Comment: do you test it on emulator or device?

Comment: Yes, I test with both, emulator and device. But still not running

Comment: show us your manifest file also have you referenced googl play services library project. you should test it on a device

Comment: change this `android:minSdkVersion="11"` to android:minSdkVersion="12"`.

Comment: thank, But this still not working.

Comment: with the info posted that's all i can suggest. check if you have referenced google play services librry project

Comment: this is link "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start" I was follow.

Comment: if you follow all the steps it should work. if not you might have not followed the steps properly.

Comment: My logcat has error " Binary XML file #2: Error inflating class fragment" What is error?

Answer (score 0):

from your error: `Binary XML file #2: Error inflating class fragment` it looks like the fragment can't be inflated, this might be happening like **@Raghunandan** said if you didn't referenced `google-play-service` library correctly.

Right-Click your project and choose “Properties” go
to the Android section, in the lower part check that you have the same result:

[image]

I might want to check this guide as well:

[Google Map API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: I was do it. But still don't work. I have problem. When I add "Right-Click you project and choose “Android Tools” and then choose
“Add Support Library…”: " Android Dependencies for me didn't appear google-play-services.jar and android-support-v4.jar. It has only google-play-services-lib.jar